Use the Gaussian-Hermite quadrature formula to approximate the solution of the following expression.
I am working on the following problem and would appreciate any insights:
In my recent research, I encountered a problem of numerically integrating a multidimensional function, When calculating the expectation. The amount of computation required to directly integrate the function is too large. The function form conforms to the Gaussian-Hermite quadrature formula. However, I found that there is a huge difference between the results of directly using the rectangular method and the approximation using the Gaussian-Hermite quadrature formula. The question is as follows:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{h_l^2}{N_l\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{h_l^2}{N_l}\right)\frac{\left(2y\sinh\left(\frac{2h_lx}{\sqrt{N_l}}\right)\right)^2}{\cosh\left(\frac{2h_lx}{\sqrt{N_l}}\right)}\exp(-x^2)\exp(-y^2) dx dy$$
Where $h_l$ and $N_l$ are constants
Gaussian-Hermite quadrature formula is as follows:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}f(x)dx\approx\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k^{(n)}f(\xi_k^{(n)}) $$I use the case of $n=5$, the product node $\xi_k^{(n)}$ is $-2.02018287, -0.95857246,0, 0.95857246, 2.02018287$,
and the product coefficient $\lambda_k^{(n)}$ is $0.01995324,0.39361932,0.94530872,0.39361932,0.01995324$
I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to solve this problem,

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Are you asking How to make use of nodes and weights to approximate the integral? Maybe start by ensuring you know how to work through the 1d case.
